Failed to resolve some libraries after gradle update
After upgrading Gradle from 7.4 to 8.5, these libraries can't be resolved.
It works fine on 7.4.
What could be causing the issue?"
From
 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
To
 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-bin.zip


Please post text as text, not as images.

JCenter discontinued distributing artifacts a couple of months ago.

com.jwang123.flagkit:flagkit has not been updated in 8 years, and it presumably was only distributed via JCenter
com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0 was only distributed on JCenter, and it was replaced by 1.2.1 3 years ago (distributed by Google's own Maven)
com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable has not been updated in 10 years, and presumably it was only distributed via JCenter
com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer has not been updated in 7 years, and presumably it was only distributed via JCenter

The reason this is coming to a head now is because of JCenter's shutdown and your Gradle cache presumably being cleared.
FWIW, I wrote more about this situation in my blog.
